# Let $f(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$. Let $F$ be the anti-derivative of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove $F$ is not bounded above in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Let $f(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$. Let $F$ be the anti-derivative of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove $F$ is not bounded above in $\mathbb{R}$.

First, I had already proven that for all $x\gt 0\Rightarrow \arctan(x)\lt x$ using Lagrange's theorem, if that helps. Then I proved that $x=0$ is a removable discontinuity point and defined the function as $f(x)= \frac{arctan(x)}{x}$ if $ x\neq 0, 1$ if $x=0$, so $F$ is well defined. I found that at $x=0$, $F$ has an inflection point. now I need to prove that $F$ has no upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$. I don't really know how to do it. Do I need to show that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$ diverges? I cannot find the antiderivative obviously. How do I prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

For large values of $x$ (not even that large, i.e. for $x>\tan 1$) you have the inequality $$\frac{\arctan(x)}{x} > \frac{1}{x}$$ and the antiderivative of $\frac1x$ is not bounded above in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So if I want to formally prove that for all $x\gt tan1\Rightarrow \frac{arctan(x)}{x}\gt \frac{1}{x} $ do I just show that $ \frac{arctan(x)}{x}\gt \frac{arctan(tanx1)}{tan1}=\frac {1}{tan1}$ and since $arctan(x)$ and $x$ are both increasing functions in $\mathbb{R}$ then we get $ \frac{arctan(x)}{x}\gt \frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\gt tan1$?

Comment: @NoyPerel It's simpler than that. Since $\arctan$ is an increasing function, you have, for $x>\tan 1$, the inequality $\arctan(x) > \arctan(\tan1) =1$, now simply divide that inequality by $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Overkill: by [the Shafer-Fink inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753), for any $x>0$
$$ \frac{\arctan x}{x}\geq \frac{3}{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
hence $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\arctan u}{u}\,du \geq \frac{3}{2}\text{arcsinh}(x)-O(1)$ (actually $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\arctan u}{u}\,du \geq \frac{3}{2}\text{arcsinh}(x)-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$)
 implies that $F(x)$ is unbounded. The LHS is $\text{Im}\,\text{Li}_2(ix)$.

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting to know, will read about that inequality :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $ x\ge 1$

$$f(x)=\frac{arctan(x)}{x} \ge  \frac { (\frac {\pi }{4})}{x}$$

and

$$ \int _1^{\infty}\frac { (\frac {\pi }{4})}{x} dx $$
is not bounded above.

By comparison  the $$ \int _1^{\infty}f(x) dx $$ is not bounded above.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!